# Solving a system of linear equations with derivatives inside (for spin 1/2 particle in magnetic field)

Tags: derivatives, vectors, systems-of-equations

I have been trying to solve the state vector for a spin 1/2 particle inside an oscillating magnetic field, and having managed with the field in the z axis, I tried it instead in the x-axis. This ended up in a situation that I never faced before and was stumped how to solve (it probably is easy, but I didn't know how to start...) which involved a system of non-linear equations. The state vector has the shape

$$
\chi(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha(t)\\ \beta(t)\end{pmatrix}
$$

and when we put it into the Schrodinger equation with the correct Hamiltonian, we end up with

$$
\begin{align*}
i\begin{pmatrix}\dot{\alpha}\\\dot{\beta}\end{pmatrix}&=-\frac{\gamma B_0}{2} \cos(\omega t)\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}{\alpha}\\{\beta}\end{pmatrix}\\
\Leftrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}\dot{\alpha}\\\dot{\beta}\end{pmatrix}&=\frac{i\gamma B_0}{2} \cos(\omega t)\begin{pmatrix}{\beta}\\{\alpha}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

which results in the following system that I don't know how to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{d\alpha}{dt} = \frac{i\gamma B_0}{2} \cos(\omega t)\beta\\
\frac{d\beta}{dt} = \frac{i\gamma B_0}{2} \cos(\omega t)\alpha
\end{cases}
$$
What should I be doing in a case like this? I also would like to define the initial state being to solve this.

$$
\chi(t=0) = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: That system is linear. We have $\dot{\chi}(t) = A(t)\chi(t)$ for some linear $A(t)$. I think what you're struggling with is that it is *non-autonomous*. That is, $A(t)$ depends on $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the system is linear. It takes the form $\dot{\chi}(t) = A(t) \chi(t)$ where $A(t)$ is linear.

It is, however, non-autonomous. Luckily, since $A(t)$ commutes with itself for all $t$, we have
\begin{align}
\chi(t) &= e^{\int_0^t A(s) ds} \chi(0)
\end{align}
We compute
$$
\int_0^t A(s)  ds = 
\frac{i\gamma B_0}{2 \omega} \sin(\omega t) \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
\begin{align}
e^{\int_0^t A(s) ds}
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{i\gamma B_0 \sin (\omega t)}{2\omega}\right)^n \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^n
\\&= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!} \left(\frac{i\gamma B_0 \sin (\omega t)}{2\omega}\right)^{2k} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\\&+ \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k + 1)!} \left(\frac{i\gamma B_0 \sin (\omega t)}{2\omega}\right)^{2k + 1} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\\&= \cos \left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right]\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\\&+ i \sin \left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right]\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
We conclude
\begin{align}
\chi(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right] & i \sin \left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right] \\ i \sin \left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right] &\cos \left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right] \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Or
$$
\chi(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right] \\ i\sin \left[ \frac{\gamma B_0 \sin(\omega t)}{2\omega} \right] \end{pmatrix}
$$
which you can easily verify solves the ODE.